# NASM: SegFault on MOV ECX

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to make a very simple assembly program run, however I seem to get segfaults whatever I do.

Here is my code (should print 'a' on a linux machine)

```
section .data
    buffer times 50 db 97
    pointer db 0
section .text
    global _start
    _start:
    mov ECX , pointer
    mov EDX , [buffer + ECX]
    mov EAX , 4
    mov EBX , 1
    mov ECX , EDX
    mov EDX , 1
    int 0x80
```

It causes a segfault on the first MOV but it seems obvious to me that it should work.

I reduced it to almost nothing and it still segfault.

```
section .data
    msg db "hello"
section .text
    global _start
    _start:
    mov EAX,1
```

I've run this succesfully:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:

    mov ax, 0b
    dec ax
    sub ax, 11111111b

    mov bx, 97

    add ax, bx

    mov [INVENTORY], ax ; put a in first inventory pos


    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, INVENTORY      
    mov edx, 1        
    int 0x80

    mov ax, [INVENTORY]
    add ax, 1
    mov [INVENTORY + 1], ax ; put b in second inventory pos
    mov [VAR], ax

    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, VAR    
    mov edx, 1        
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, '\n'         
    mov edx, 1        
    int 0x80

    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

_newline:


section .data

VAR DW 0
INVENTORY TIMES 8 DW 0
```

Is it possible that it has to do with the symbols I use for newlines or tabs? I generate the assembly from java and I use \t for tabs and \n for new lines (and spaces so it doesn't look too bad.

I'm using NASM and I'm running it here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php

Thank you!

Comment: In your simple examples you must call the _EXIT_ syscall to leave your program.

Comment: I did add an EXIT syscall, without avail

Comment: I'm using the link in my post to compile and run, I'm not sure what exact OS but it's a linux box.

Comment: @SamuelYvon in your shell try to enter "lsb_release -a" - without quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to print out a set of 'a's.

```
section .data
        buffer times 50 db 97
        len.buffer equ $-buffer
        pointer db 0
section .text
    global _start

_start:
        ; ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
        ; i386             ebx              ecx            edx   esi   edi   ebp
        mov EAX , 4             ; write syscall
        mov EBX , 1             ; std out
        lea ecx, [buffer]       ; buffer
        mov edx, len.buffer     ; size
        int 0x80

_exit:
        mov eax, 1              ; exit syscall
        int 0x80
```

output:

```
./yvon_001
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\ndavid@ubuntuserver00A:~/asm$ ./yvon_001
```

Comment: I'm writing a brainf**k compiler, I'm doing some tests before

Comment: @SamuelYvon - did you post something on Reddit earlier?

Comment: Nope! I actually ended up making it works I'll post a more detailed answer later, I'm having other issues but that will be another post if I don't figure it out

Comment: @SamuelYvon - I see. Are working on flushing the buffer; i.e., clearing stdin?

Comment: No, not for now. I try to focus on base operations (move left, right, increment the memory, decrement and loops)

Answer (score 0):

In the end @MichealPetch was right, I needed to add an EXIT syscall at the end of the code. The sample I tried still did a SEGFAULT because I was moving pointer instead of [pointer] in a registry.

Thanks for comments and answers!